# Does the acceptance of a 'legitimate aim' in the context of Article 8 ECHR also imply its acceptance in the context of Article 14 ECHR?

Tags: discrimination, human-rights, european-court-of-human-rights

Suppose that the European Court of Human Rights qualifies a certain policy aim, such as the protection of the Member State's health system, as constituting a 'legitimate aim' in the context of Article 8 ECHR. Does this imply that this aim would also be found legitimate in cases arising under Article 14 ECHR? Or are the 'legitimate aims' accepted under each of these provisions totally unrelated?

Comment: Do you want to know if the legitimate aims are accepted as legitimate under all provisions, or do you really want to know if an alleged breach of rights can be justified in the same way?

Comment: I am not exactly sure I understand the difference, but maybe I am looking to find clues that the ECtHR will, once it has found that a certain infringement of one of the convention rights (e.g. right to family life) has a legitimate aim (e.g. protection of health system), it will rely on this finding in later cases relating to infringements of other convention rights (e.g. right to non-discrimination) to hold that these infringements also had a legitimate aim. Does this perhaps clarify my question?

Comment: The difference is that legitimate aim alone is not enough to justify infringements.